# Elements in a Vector that start with a given letter/number

Tags: java, search, vector, methods

I am trying to find on a Vector how many indexes start with a given letter or number.

I've tried `vector.indexOf("A");` and `vector.lastIndexOf("A");` but of course they are "useless" for what I am trying to do because those try to find a position that only have "A" and nothing else.

I wanted to know if there is a Java method to do this or if I need to do it "by myself", if so, a little guiding on the how-to process would be thanked.

Comment: Use a loop. Or, if using Java 8, a Stream. Note that Vector shouldn't be used anymore, and that has been true for 15 years. Use ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to (or can) use streams or lambdas you can also use this little loop here:

```
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        count = vec.get(i).charAt(0)=='A' ? count+1 : count;
    }
```

No big thing, just checking each element if it starts with A and then counting up.

Comment: Nice and simple, I needed to tweak it here and there to adapt it to my code but other than that I cannot think of a better solution. Thanks a lot @Jankapunkt

Answer (score 1):

In Java8 you can use [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to access functional-style operations such as `filter()` and `count()`. Use the `stream()` method to get a Stream on your collection.

Comment: I will definetly check them out, thanks a lot for the info Julien. Sadly I can only accept one question or I would give it to both of you.

Comment: @this.user3272243 That will teach me not to post the code I guess. :p Be sure to have a look at streams and other features of Java 8 anyway, this version greatly improves the language so it would be a shame not to use it.